# Replacing with ignoring few characters using SED

Tags: shell, sed

I have a problem while replacing the below function to macro.

original line:

```
function("<message>);
```

required line:

```
`macro("message")
```

i.e. a function must be changed to macro in multiple files(different message each time) and with semicolon removed. I tried below command.

```
grep -rl 'function' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/function/`macro/g'
```

This solved half of my issue. i.e replacing the front part before the message. I got stuck while replacing the semicolon.

Note: other semicolons must not be disturbed.

Comment: can you show some sample examples on how can be `message` text? can it have spaces? Note also you have a leading ` and, also, your "function" part does not contain a closing double quote. Should it be like this?

Comment: For your exact output you could use `sed 's/function("<\([^>]*\)>.*/\`macro("\1")/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backreference to do the whole update:

```
grep -rl 'function' ./ | \
  xargs sed -i 's/function("<\(.*\)>);/`macro("\1")/g'
```

Comment: Got my mistake. Its all about matching. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
grep -rl 'function' ./ | xargs sed -i '/function/{s/function/`macro/g;s/;\s*$//}'
```

Comment: `Note: other semicolons must not be disturbed.`. Why not making the full regex for the `function` lines?

Comment: I didn't read that line... you are right, then `function` should be checked as pattern.

Comment: Yep! In fact, you can also say `find . -exec sed ... {} \;`, there is no need for the `grep -r`.